# How to enable optional client certificate requests in GlassFish?

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, glassfish-3, client-certificates

The [Blog site (Client-Auth REQUESTED in GlassFish)](http://blogs.oracle.com/kalpana/entry/client_auth_requested_in_glassfish) reads:

```
In domain.xml, please add the following property to http-listener element
<property name="com.sun.grizzly.ssl.auth" value="want"/>
```

However, when adding this to my GlassFish v3 domain.xml, the existing browser client certificate is not requested. The GlassFish server is properly set up, i.e., requires client certificates with the option "client-auth-enabled" set to true.

The GlassFish bugtracker (1) mentions a different version:

```
 * client-auth: want/need/<blank>
```

However, this property doesn't get accepted either.

Others have the same problem (2).

How can I enable an optional client certificate request in GlassFish? Are there alternatives?

(1) http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-6935
(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634129/configure-glassfish-v3-client-auth-requested-to-want

Comment: According to that JIRA issue, it's been added in GlassFish 3.1.2
Any version prior to that won't have that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because it doesn't exist.

*When you deal with client certificates in HTTPS, keep in mind your HTTPS listener configurations. The SSLv3/TLS protocol allows three modes for an HTTPS socket.

```
* The traditional mode requires a single server certificate. An HTTPS client (typically a web browser) validates the server identity by matching the certificate to a list, or truststore, of Certificate Authorities. You probably use this mode every day during typical log-in activity.

* Another mode requires both client and server certificates. The client certificate is validated by the server side, and the server certificate is validated by the client side.

* The third mode requires a server certificate, but the client certificate is optional.
```

*In the real world, you want to use the same HTTPS URL whether a user is authenticated by password or certificate. This approach requires a server that supports the third, optional client certificate mode. At this writing, the GlassFish application server does not support this mode. Fortunately, the Apache Tomcat web server, supported by OpenSSO, is available as an alternative. For [Reference](http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/opensso_protect.html)